# Where is the actual implementation of "__getattribute__"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

I can't find the Python source code for `__getattribute__`. I looked in "object", and "type" classes, but I only see the function declaration. I don't see the actual definition.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/187949ebf2ae36fcf0817a06f4a7637d0a8b7fc5/Objects/object.c#L898)

Comment: Just to add on, the reason it's not accessible normally is because the definition is not written in python, but rather C.

Comment: @Alexander: That's the implementation of the C-level counterpart of the `getattr` builtin, not `__getattribute__`.

Comment: @user2357112  the point is that there is no python implementation of getattribute it is it is executed by the interpreter in C.

Comment: if you're looking to extend __getattribute__ functionality, you would call object.__getattribute__( self , arg ) after  you apply your logic to arg (dont use super). Just be aware that it's called by other internals, so make sure that cases where you aren't applying custom logic gets passed through as well.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, there is no Python fallback implementation of `object.__getattribute__` in cPython.

Following the source code, we see that the C function ultimately bound to the default `object.__getattribute__` (as of main branch in Aug-2022) is `_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict`, located here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ccf94a6289c722f56000ffed5dd416371127c759/Objects/object.c#L1242

As documented in the language, it will first lookup for a data-descriptor in the object class, then check if the object has a `__dict__`, and perform the lookup there. The fallback to an attribute or descriptor defined in base classes when performing both lookups is not encoded in `_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict` and rather takes place automatically in the functions called by it.

The Bytecode opcode "LOAD_METHOD" to retrieve a method will go through the sibling function `_PyObject_GetMethod` instead (line 1139, in the same file) - you will see there are comments around indicating both methods must stay in sync - as, from the point of view of Python code, both an attribute lookup and a method retrieval go through `object.__getattribute__`.